# Trying to create a fixed vignette over a webpage

Tags: css, html, repeat

I want to overlay a vignette over a webpage.  The vignette will be fixed to the visible part of the page (i.e. the window) and the page will scroll up and down underneath it.  I figure there must be a better way to do it than the way I am trying (which isn't working).

What I have tried is to have the 4 corners of the vignette as 4 separate images, that are positioned as "fixed" and have an increased z-index.  That works fine.  But I want to fill in the gaps between the corner images.  I have created a couple of thin slices of the appropriate area of the vignette that I was hoping to repeat between the corners.  But I can't seem to arrange my divs in a way that allows me to fill in the gaps.  At the moment I have 4 corner parts of the vignette, with nothing in between the corners.

Here's a part of the code where I try and organise the divs.  The "left" and "right" class of divs are floated respectively:

```
<body onload="sizeDivs()" onresize="sizeDivs()">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="vignette"><img id="vignette_topleft" src="code/images/vignette_topleft.png"/></div>
        <div class="vignette_side" id="vignette_left"></div>
        <div class="vignette"><img id="vignette_bottomleft" src="code/images/vignette_bottomleft.png"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="vignette_top-bottom" id="vignette_top"></div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="vignette"><img id="vignette_topright" src="code/images/vignette_topright.png"/></div>
        <div class="vignette_side" id="vignette_right"></div>
        <div class="vignette"><img id="vignette_bottomright" src="code/images/vignette_bottomright.png"/></div>
    </div>
```

The  events are javascript functions which determine the size of fill-in divs required and then sets their heights.

The CSS for top, left and right fill is:

```
.vignette {
        z-index: 5;
    }

    .vignette_top-bottom {
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        z-index: 5;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #vignette_topleft {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    #vignette_bottomleft {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    #vignette_topright {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    #vignette_bottomright {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    #vignette_left {
        background-image: url("code/images/vignette_left.png");
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        position: relative;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    #vignette_right {
        background-image: url("code/images/vignette_rightred.png");
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        position: relative;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    #vignette_top {
        background-image: url("code/images/vignette_top.png");
        position: relative;
    }
```

You'll see various combinations of positioning in there, but it doesn't seem to make much of a difference how I position the fill bits.

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.vignette {
    position: fixed;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10em #000;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10em #000;   
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10em #000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Yes! That works.  Thank you.  Can you tell me how to darken the vignette using this method?

Comment: You can try stacking them at different sizes

Answer (score 3):

Don't know how good this is for performance, but: http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/onapH

```
html:before {
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 content:"";
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 220px black inset;

 pointer-events:none;
 z-index:1000;

 }
```

No extra markup!

(This is basically a full page CSS3 box shadow)